# Rails named route & helper (/controller/:id/randomname)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, helper

I'm trying to get the following routing to work:

```
get 'items/:id/pictures' => 'pictures#show'
```

What kind of helper method should I use ? Using `<%= link_to pictures_item_path do %>` I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `pictures_item_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fa2c6181710>:0x007fa2c40ba7c0>
```

I've tried using `get 'items/:id/pictures' => 'pictures#show', as: 'items/:id/pictures'` and I get the following error:

```
Invalid route name: 'items_:id_pictures'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route is correct. If you're going to use a helper, you have to use [Named routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes).

Routes can be named by passing an `:as` option, allowing for easy reference within your source as `name_of_route_url` for the full URL and `name_of_route_path` for the URI path:

```
# In routes.rb
get '/login', to: 'accounts#login', as: :login

# With render, redirect_to, tests, etc.
redirect_to login_url
```

I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**routes.rb**

```
get 'items/:id/pictures' => 'pictures#show'
```

execute this command on console

```
rake routes
```

you will get the result like this

```
pictures_item GET    /items/:id/pictures(.:format)   pictures#show
```

You have to use `pictures_item_path(:id)` or `pictures_item_url(:id)` because it is member route

try this:

```
<%= link_to 'item picture', pictures_item_path(@item_id) %>
```

Read more about [routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)